# L (long) postfix in boost erf(): when is needed and when not?

Tags: c++, math, boost, floating-point, floating-point-precision

In the Boost implementation of [erf function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

[image]

in a header `<boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp>` we have

```
result = z * 1.125 + z * 0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688L;
```

in the code snippet attached below. My question is: why there is no

> L

long postfix in the first component of this addition while there is one in the second? What is a rationale behind it and what implications does it introduce?

```
template <class T, class Policy>
T erf_imp(T z, bool invert, const Policy& pol, const mpl::int_<113>& t)
{
   BOOST_MATH_STD_USING
   BOOST_MATH_INSTRUMENT_CODE("113-bit precision erf_imp called");

   if(z < 0){
      if(!invert)
         return -erf_imp(-z, invert, pol, t);
      else if(z < -0.5)
         return 2 - erf_imp(-z, invert, pol, t);
      else
         return 1 + erf_imp(-z, false, pol, t);
   }

   T result;

   // Big bunch of selection statements now
   if(z < 0.5){
      // We're going to calculate erf:
      if(z == 0){
         result = 0;
      }else if(z < 1e-20){
         result = z * 1.125 + z * 0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688L;
                          ^^^ no L?                                       ^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `z` is already a `long double`, then the multiplication `z * 1.125` is already a `long double` multiplication.
The constant `1.125` is exactly representable as a `double`, its type. In fact, it would be exactly representable as a `float`. So there is no need to indicate the type `long double` for this constant. If `z` has a wider floating-point type, then the constant is promoted before the multiplication anyway.

By contrast, the real number written in decimal 0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688 is not representable exactly in any binary floating-point precision. If `0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688L` was written `0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688` in the program, it would represent the nearest `double` to the decimal sequence indicated, which is different from the nearest `long double`, and further away from the real value.

You can observe the difference with the C program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
  printf("%s\n%.24Lf\n%.24Lf\n\n%La\n%La\n", 
     "0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688",
     (long double) 0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688,
     0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688L,
     (long double) 0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688,
     0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688L);
}
```

Result:

```
0.003379167095512573896158903121545171688
0.003379167095512573739530
0.003379167095512573896231

0xd.d750429b6d118p-12
0xd.d750429b6d11ae4p-12
```

Comment: how did you determine that 1.125 is representable exactly as a double?

Comment: @gumtree: That's 1 + 0.125 = 2^0 + 2^(-3).

Comment: OK, but result is T, this is not necessary long type

Comment: @gumtree it is difficult in general but 1.125 is just 1 + 1/8, or 1 + 1/2^3, so one only needs a 3-bit significand or more to represent this particular number exactly as a binary floating-point number.

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain When several computations take place, it makes sense to use `long double` computations for intermediate results even if the final result will only be narrower. For instance, computing correctly rounded `sin()` or `cos()` with 53 bits of precision (`double`) require a little more than 100 bits of precision for intermediate results.

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain I was not counting the implicitly set bit in the IEEE 754 floating-point representation when I said “3 bits”. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: @PascalCuoq so the root reason is that 1.125 has exact long representation? then what if it was a number that doesn't have such exact representation? it is like second term, and thats why there L is needed?

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain If 1.125 was not exactly representable, then it would make sense to use `long double` to represent the best possible approximation of this constant, just like `long double` is used to represent the other constant.

Comment: @PascalCuoq and then L would be must also in the first term of equation?